# Android multitouch issue

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

So I'm working on a game where two players play simultaneously on one screen. For the sake of simplicity let's say both players have one button on their side of the screen, buttons B[0] and B[1]. I want to implement multitouch so that both buttons can be pressed with no unresponsiveness, but as soon as one of them does ACTION_DOWN on his button, the other one becomes unresponsive. I read all the duplicate questions and understood that the second touch would be referenced as ACTION_POINTER_DOWN so I wrote this piece of code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View buttonPressed, MotionEvent action) 
    {
        if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[0].getId())
        {
             if(action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                B[0].setImageDrawable(BPressed[0]);
             if(action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
                B[0].setImageDrawable(BOk[0]);    
        }
        if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[1].getId())
        {
             if(action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                B[1].setImageDrawable(BPressed[1]);
             if(action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
                B[1].setImageDrawable(BOk[1]);    
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So as far I can tell if I put 1 finger on B[0] and leave it there (no ACTION_UP) and then put another on B[1] the listener should fire onTouch(B[1],ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) but i think it doesn't since when I do that B[0] has BPressed drawable and B[1] has BOk drawable. Where did I go wrong? Sorry if I made a duplicate, but I read everything and can't seem to find a simple solution. Every solution regarding this issue I found gives much more than I need.

Both buttons are connected with the listener like this:

```
B[0].setOnTouchListener(this);
B[1].setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I've read this:

```
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_UP are fired whenever a secondary pointer goes down or up.
```

But it doesn't seem to be true.

EDIT:

The new code, still the same result:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View buttonPressed, MotionEvent action) 
        {
if( buttonPressed.getId()==B[1].getId() )
             Toast.makeText(context, "One", 500).show();
    int act = action.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

            if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[0].getId())
            {
                 if(act == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                    B[0].setImageDrawable(BPressed[0]);
                 if(act == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
                    B[0].setImageDrawable(BOk[0]);    
            }
            if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[1].getId())
            {
                 if(act == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                    B[1].setImageDrawable(BPressed[1]);
                 if(act == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || act == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
                    B[1].setImageDrawable(BOk[1]);    
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Also, the toast:

```
if( buttonPressed.getId()==B[1].getId() )
         Toast.makeText(context, "One", 500).show();
```

can never be seen if I keep my finger on B[0].

**After masking:**

Something changed. Let's say I hold my finger on B[0]. Before the masking when I press B[1] nothing happens. After masking if I keep my finger on B[0], and I tap my finger ANYWHERE on the screen it cycles the B[0]. So if I go:

```
finger1_DOWN on B[0] it changes to Pressed drawable
while(1)
{
finger2_DOWN anywhere nothing changes
finger2_UP anywhere B[0] changes to Ok drawable
}
```

I create my imagebuttons in OnCreate:

```
B[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton05);
B[0].setOnTouchListener(this);
B[1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton15);
B[1].setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I tried jboi's approach. I don't care if the button was pressed first or second so I just did this:

```
private class MPListener implements OnTouchListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View buttonPressed, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[0].getId())
                   B[0].setImageDrawable(BPressed[0]);

                if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[1].getId())
                  B[1].setImageDrawable(BPressed[1]);
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[0].getId())
                   B[0].setImageDrawable(BOk[0]);

                if(buttonPressed.getId()==B[1].getId())
                  B[1].setImageDrawable(BOk[1]);
            }
        return true;
        }
    }
```

I removed implements onTouchListener from my activity and added

```
B[0].setOnTouchListener(new MPListener());
B[1].setOnTouchListener(new MPListener());
```

Nothing changed. I can still press both buttons independently, but not at the same time.

**EDIT:**
So I made a fresh new activity in case something else was the problem. Here's my new activity's **full** code:

```
package com.example.projectname;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class About extends Activity
{

    private class MPListener implements OnTouchListener 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
            {
                if(v.getId()==B[0].getId())
                    B[0].setImageDrawable(Bok[0]);
                if(v.getId()==B[1].getId())
                    B[1].setImageDrawable(Bok[1]);
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            {
                if(v.getId()==B[0].getId())
                    B[0].setImageDrawable(Bpressed[0]);
                if(v.getId()==B[1].getId())
                    B[1].setImageDrawable(Bpressed[1]);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    ImageView[] B;
    Drawable[] Bok,Bpressed;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //standard oncreate stuff
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        Context context=getApplicationContext();

        B=new ImageView[2];
        Bok=new Drawable[2];
        Bpressed=new Drawable[2];

        Bok[0] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bblue);
        Bok[1] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bpurp);
        Bpressed[0] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bpressedblue);
        Bpressed[1] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bpressedpurp);

        B[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        B[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        B[0].setImageDrawable(Bok[0]);
        B[1].setImageDrawable(Bok[1]);

        B[0].setOnTouchListener(new MPListener());
        B[1].setOnTouchListener(new MPListener());
    }
}
```

Everything is the same as always. As soon as I press one button the other one goes unresponsive.

Comment: It's obvious that if you touched B[0] first (and did not release), and then touch B[1], this means that B[1] will get `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` event, because it's for second touch. You should add check up for `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` for B[1] in the same way as for B[0].

Comment: @Stan Oh, it's just a typo. It still doesn't work when I fix it. Also it doesn't work the other way around (B[1] -> B[0])

Comment: You should check action after applying the mask: `if(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK == ...)`.

Comment: It still doesn't work, look at my edit.

Comment: Try return false. Also this may be a matter of your container view. Provide some info about it.

Comment: Look at my latest edit. Returning false doesn't help but masking changed something. What part of my code do you need?

Comment: I can put up to four fingers on the screen. As long as the first was on B[0] all the fingers control B[0]...

Comment: The real problem is that the argument ButtonPressed is wrong. It always points to the button I pressed first.

Comment: You should assign container view, where both buttons reside, the handler of touches (not buttons themselves). Then in the onTouch use button1.isPressed and button2.isPressed.

Comment: I might try that later, thanks. I will work on jboi's approach first.

Answer (score 1):

Android can sort out for you, what was pressed in what order and if it is still touched or not. Just give the two Buttons **different** listeners. Something like this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TEST", "Begin onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TEST", "End   onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    findViewById(R.id.upperTouchable).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.lowerTouchable).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
}

private boolean lowerIsTouched = false;
private boolean upperIsTouched = false;

private void setInfo() {
    if(lowerIsTouched && upperIsTouched)
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("both touched");
    else if(lowerIsTouched)
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("only lower is touched");
    else if(upperIsTouched)
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("only upper is touched");
    else
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.info)).setText("non is touched");

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lowerTouchable)).setText(lowerIsTouched? "touched":"not touched");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.upperTouchable)).setText(upperIsTouched? "touched":"not touched");
}

private class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.lowerTouchable)
                lowerIsTouched = true;
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.upperTouchable)
                upperIsTouched = true;
            setInfo();
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.lowerTouchable)
                lowerIsTouched = false;
            else if(v.getId() == R.id.upperTouchable)
                upperIsTouched = false;
            setInfo();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the corresponding layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
android:text="Non touched"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/upperTouchable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Not touched"
    android:background="#FFF0F0F0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lowerTouchable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Not touched"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I made an edit, check it out. I will try modifying your code to see if it can possibly work. I added ACTION_POINTER_UP parts of the code and your approach seems to change nothing. It's the same as when I implemented a listener directly in my class.

Comment: If seen your edit. I think I still dont understand fully, what exact behavior you're looking for. Let me explain in my words: A button can have three states: "Unpressed", "pressed", "unresponsive". Two buttons exist on the screen. Initially both buttons are in state "unpressed". If one button is pressed, then this get into state "pressed" and the other button into state "unresponsive". If the other button is now touched, it does not react. If the first button is released, both button turn into stae "unpressed". Is that all right? If, so I can change my code, to fullfil that. Just let me know.

Comment: Ok, that's not what I'm looking for. I want two buttons, both always responsive. Both buttons can be pressed and unpressed. The thing you described is the thing I'm getting, exactly. But that's not what I need. I don't want unresponsive buttons. I hope I made it clear, thanks :)

Comment: The buttons are unpressed whenever you dont press them, of course.

Comment: I think your last edit and my last edit are same. Where is the difference? And the "two instances part", I don't get it. Sorry for my incompetence, but I would really appreciate your help since my project kinda depends on it (the deadline is in two days)

Comment: I even used two different listener classes and it still failed. There is a game on my phone that supports multi touch so I'm certain it's possible. I'm getting pretty desperate now. Let's call it a day, I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: I was just cleaning my test to post it and had an idea to test up front. What view type are you using? Are these TextView or Button? With Buttons the image might overlap with the click logic of the Button itself. Can you test with TextView or plain ImageView, please? If this is still not working I post ky full test code here. Somehow we should get this thing to work.

Comment: They're imagebuttons. I'll try with imageviews now.

Comment: Hi, I was in a plane from San Francisco to Frankfurt yesterday. I've replaced nearly all of my answer with just my test code. Works perfect on my devices. If you copy it and try it out and it does not work, than you can consider this as bug somewhere in your devices, Android Version etc.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe it's something related to my app settings (Manifest or something). I could copy your whole project if that is the case, but I doubt it. If you think that could be it, and it's not a big problem for you, provide the whole project.

Comment: On the other hand, I am testing on Xperia Arc S, android version 2.3.4. The problem is, for example, the game "Wizard Wars" from the play store uses multitouch, and it works. So there must be another way that works on my device.

Comment: Funny enough I tried it on a Xperia Arc S with Android 4.0.4 on it and it works. My Manifest is completely straight forward and default. Nothing special. Strange...

Comment: Yeah but maybe my app manifest is corrupt. I'm working on it for a month, who knows what I added that might mess things up. I should try testing on a completely new app. Give me a minute.

Comment: Nope. That's not it. I could try on 4.0+ Android versions but I still want my app to support various phones, so that won't do any good.

Comment: The multi touch support was added with API level 8, Android 2.2.

Comment: I have tested your multitouch on Htc one (4.2.2) and Galaxy s4 (4.3), and it works. But on my Arc and on Alcatel one touch (2.3.6) it doesn't. Wonder why. The good thing is that it works somewhere...

Comment: It works on S3(4.1.2.), also. Could the settings like Target API pose a problem? I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I will ask a new, rephrased question, now that I have more info.

Comment: It might be a matter of different devices and Android Versions. I would expect, that some Android 2.x devices will not support multi touch on the hardware level. But I'm out of my competence here anyway. If the rest did help you, please upvote (if not, not :-)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, there are apps with multitouch that work. That's what troubles me. Of course you'll get an upvote, thanks for all your help :)